# Azure rest api for retain vhds

Tags: rest, azure

In the azure management portal, when we go to virtual machines -> disks -> delete, there are two options that are displayed "Delete the associated VHD" and "Retain the associated VHD".

I have the REST API for delete the associated VHD, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157179.aspx.

Could anyone let me know the REST API call for retaining the associated VHD please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157179.aspx) you mentioned above:

> comp=media   Optional. Specifies that the source blob for the disk should also be
>   deleted from storage.
>
> The comp=media parameter is only available using version 2013-08-01
>   and higher.

If I understand correctly, in order to retain the VHD (i.e. not delete it from the storage account), you just have to not include this parameter in your request URL.